# Obtain count to MI:SSSS precision?

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, oracle12c

**TRANSACTION_DATE** is a **DATE** data type.

This code lists all of the event dates to the MI:SSSS.

`select to_char(transaction_date,'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SSSS') as trans_date from ticket_orders;`

Now I want to get counts for those dates and I get ORA-00979 not a GROUP BY function.

```
    select to_char(transaction_date,'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SSSS') as trans_date,
     count(*)
      from ticket_orders
       group by to_char(transaction_date,'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SSSS');
```

**ERROR** `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

How do I get a count of transactions to the `MI:SSSS` precision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DATE` data type does not store fractional seconds. You can reference the [Oracle documentation about data types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6).

> DATE
>
> Valid date range from January 1, 4712 BC, to December 31, 9999 AD. The
> default format is determined explicitly by the NLS_DATE_FORMAT
> parameter or implicitly by the NLS_TERRITORY parameter. The size is
> fixed at 7 bytes. This data type contains the datetime fields YEAR,
> MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. It does not have fractional
> seconds or a time zone.

If you want a data type that stores fractional seconds you will need to use `TIMESTAMP`

> TIMESTAMP [(fractional_seconds_precision)]
>
> Year, month, and day values of date, as well as hour, minute, and
> second values of time, where fractional_seconds_precision is the
> number of digits in the fractional part of the SECOND datetime field.
> Accepted values of fractional_seconds_precision are 0 to 9. The
> default is 6. The default format is determined explicitly by the
> NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT parameter or implicitly by the NLS_TERRITORY
> parameter. The size is 7 or 11 bytes, depending on the precision. This
> data type contains the datetime fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE,
> and SECOND. It contains fractional seconds but does not have a time
> zone.

Comment: If `DATE` type does not store fractional seconds, why does a typical row from my first query look like this `2021-FEB-25 07:58:2626` ?

Comment: `SSSS` is not how to display fractional seconds. Fractional seconds are displayed with `FFFF`. Seconds are displayed with `SS` so you are displaying the seconds value twice.

Comment: If you run the query `select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS.FFFF') from dual` you will get an error because a `DATE` does not hold fractional seconds. If you execute `select to_char(systimestamp,'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS.FFFF') from dual` you will see fractional seconds.

Comment: So, since the TRANSACTION_DATE is DATE data type, then I'm out of luck on obtaining anything more precise?  Seconds is the best I've got.

Comment: Correct. You will need to convert the column to a TIMESTAMP datatype if you want fractional seconds. If you do convert your column, any existing data will display 000000 for the fractional seconds, but any new or updated records can hold the fractional seconds.

Answer (score 3):

A `DATE` data type is a binary data type that is composed of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those components and it **NEVER** contains fractional seconds (that is for the `TIMESTAMP` data type which can have fractional seconds and/or time zone information).

> If `DATE` type does not store fractional seconds, why does a typical row from my first query look like this `2021-FEB-25 07:58:2626`

That is because you are displaying the seconds twice as you use the `SS` format model for seconds twice.

Your query can just be:

```sql
select to_char(transaction_date,'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') as trans_date,
       count(*)
from   ticket_orders
group by
       transaction_date;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=27473f9982abecaf5e3f4c958f087633)*